# Firebase Cloud Functions Authentication createUser unkown error

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an API under Firebase Cloud Functions and **express**. I'm trying to develop a function that creates a user and set up his profile at the same time.

**The problem:** the function doesn't go further than the **createUser** method. The endpoint returns error 500 and a null response.

I realized that it was the **createUser** method because I inserted a *console.log* sentence before and after the function createUser like:

```
console.log('before createUser sentence');

const user = await admin.auth().createUser(...);

console.log('after createUser sentence');
```

The sentence before the createUser function was executed but the instruction after the createUser function it was never executed.

I tried without async/await (with the then/catch sentence) and nothing occurs.

As you can see, I divided the creation of the user in two parts: the creation, properly said, and the user fields update. It was in order to find a workaround due to the mysterious **createUser** error and stayed that way.

Thanks for your time!

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

import * as express from 'express';

const api = express();

// Express middleware that validates Firebase ID Tokens passed in the Authorization HTTP header.
// The Firebase ID token needs to be passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization HTTP header like this:
// `Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`.
// when decoded successfully, the ID Token content will be added as `req.user`.
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    console.log('Check if request is authorized with Firebase ID token');

    if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.',
                      'Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:',
                      'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>');

        res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }

    const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];

    try {
        const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
        console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
        req.user = decodedIdToken;
        next();
        return;
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', err);

        res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }
};

const valid = (type: any, value: any) => {
    if (!value) return false;

    if (type === 'email') {
        const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return emailRegex.test(String(value).toLowerCase());
    }
    else if (type === 'phone') {
        const argPhoneRegex = /^(?:(?:00)?549?)?0?(?:11|[2368]\d)(?:(?=\d{0,2}15)\d{2})??\d{8}$/;
        return argPhoneRegex.test(String(value).toLowerCase());
    }
    else if (type === 'password') {
        return value.length >= 6;
    }
    else if (type === 'name') {
        return value.length >= 3;
    }
}

api.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);

api.post('/register-user', async (req: any, res: any) => {    
    const email = req.body.email || false;
    const password  = req.body.password || false;
    const firstname  = req.body.firstname || false;
    const lastname  = req.body.lastname || false;
    const phone  = req.body.phone || false;

    if (!valid('email', email) ||
        !valid('password', password) ||
        !valid('name', firstname) ||
        !valid('name', lastname) ||
        !valid('phone', phone)) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: true,
            message: 'Params missing'
        });
    }

    try {
        const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password
        });
        const userFields = {
            emailVerified: false,
            displayName: `${firstname} ${lastname}`,
            phoneNumber: phone,
            disabled: false
        };
        const userProfile = {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            phone
        };

        await Promise.all([
            admin.firestore().doc(`profiles/${user.uid}`).set(userProfile),
            admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, userFields)
        ]);

        res.status(200).json({ 
            profile: userProfile
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: true,
            message: err.getMessage()
        });
    }
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(api);
```

### **THE SOLUTION**

I was missing the credentials inside the `admin.initializeApp();` like the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) says.

Thank you @ErnestasButa!

Comment: Please edit the question: What exactly is the "mysterious createUser error"? How do you know that "the function doesn't go further than the createUser method"?  We don't have enough information to see what's going on here.  You will have to do some debugging and show us the logs of what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: unlike firebase-functions, firebase-admin requires user credentials when initializing instance. That's probably the main problem. you can see explanation in the docks here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: @ErnestasButa you were right!

Comment: Glad to hear :)